# Symfony hack - Executing shell script to rewrite yaml files

Tags: php, symfony, akeneo

I am using akeneo pim that uses symfony 3.4 to solve some clients desires. So this is my first time using symfony and I run into some problems. What I need to do is to create user interface, where user can add his own translations for the main menu. And those translations are coming from /translation/jsmessages.en.yml configuration file. So I have created a bundle, change the yaml file and everything is almost done. But now when I change yaml file I need to clear cache, dump the translations, run the webpack, otherwise the menu text change will not be visible. So I wanted to create shell script to do that. Something like this:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    (new YmlReader())->readYmlFile();

    exec('rm -rf ./web/bundles/* ./web/css/* ./web/js/*');
    exec('rm -rf web/js/translations/*');
    exec('php bin/console pim:install:assets --env=prod');
    exec('php bin/console assets:install --symlink web');
    exec('php bin/console oro:translation:dump');
    exec('yarn run webpack');

    return $this->render('PimcWhiteLabelBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
}
```

But this is not working, maybe because it executes the script as the www-data user, I don't know. And now I am trying to create command. Is there a good way of doing this through symfony, if someone knows, what is the best path of doing this in symfony. So I created a command, I just need direction how to approach this:

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $argument = $input->getArgument('argument');

    if ($input->getOption('option')) {
        // my exec commands
    }

    $output->writeln('Command result.');
}
```

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: You said "This is not working", what exactly? Can you provide any error message? output?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I added an answer, however I don't know if that is the best way to do this, but it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with exec command, it started to work for some reason :)

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    exec('rm -rf web/js/translations/*');
    exec('php bin/console pim:install:assets --env=prod');
    exec('php bin/console assets:install --symlink web');
    exec('php bin/console oro:translation:dump');
    exec('yarn run webpack');

    $output->writeln('Translations dumped successfully.');
}
```

Comment: You can use also Symfony Process Component: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html